# Cargo can not find msvc linker

Tags: windows, rust, visual-c++, rust-cargo

I'm trying to use rust on windows and I've installed Visual Studio with the "Desktop development with c++" toggled. See this image:

[image]

I've even added the linker to my path and can run it via PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\themo\git\glow> link
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.38.33135.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

 usage: LINK [options] [files] [@commandfile]

...
```

Yet cargo can not find it... what am I missing?

```
PS C:\Users\themo\git\glow> cargo run -r
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.76
   Compiling serde v1.0.195
   Compiling crossbeam-utils v0.8.17
   Compiling windows_x86_64_msvc v0.48.5
error: linker `C:/usr/local/bin/lld` not found
  |
  = note: The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3)

note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found

note: please ensure that Visual Studio 2017 or later, or Build Tools for Visual Studio were installed with the Visual C++ option.

note: VS Code is a different product, and is not sufficient.

error: could not compile `windows_x86_64_msvc` (build script) due to 1 previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: could not compile `serde` (build script) due to 1 previous error
error: could not compile `crossbeam-utils` (build script) due to 1 previous error
error: could not compile `proc-macro2` (build script) due to 1 previous error
```

Comment: I think the link.exe message is misleading. The path it looked for is a linux path, which is unusual for windows. Do you have any custom cargo configuration in C:\Users\themo\.cargo\config.toml or a .cargo\config.toml in your project directory?

Comment: Yes, you beautiful human being. I removed the .cargo/config.toml and now it compiles! I've spent an entire day trying to get this shit to work haha. It must have been left over from my failed attempt to cross-compile to windows from mac

Answer (score 0):

I found a .cargo/config.toml file that set the linker to the wrong path. After removing the file it worked!